# single thread and multiple thread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, threadpool, pthread-join, pthread-key-create

Would anyone know a way of explaining or could you direct me to some material regarding single Thread and multiple thread? I don't understand them at all. Every explanation I read is in very complicated English.

I want to understand them completely. Either a really good article / book / website etc where this is explained well would be well appreciated.

Comment: A *thread* is substantially like a *process*, with the main distinction being that multiple threads within a process share the same address space and memory. If you can understand *multiprocessing*, *multithreading* is not much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Threads** are the smallest sequences of programmed instructions that
can be managed independently.

**Multithreading** uses multiple threads of the same process to reduce algorithm runtime. Threads of the same process run in the same memory space.